# How to insert Date and Time Objects? Php mysql error

Tags: java, php, mysql, android-studio

i am building a project on Android Studio. I want to insert date and time values on mysql database using php.

Here is my database:
[image]

Php code:

```
<?php 
 require "conn.php";
 $name = $_POST["name"];
 $date = $_POST["date"];
 $start_time = $_POST["start_time"];
 $end_time = $_POST["end_time"];

 $mysql_qry = "insert into events_data 
 (Name, Date, start_time, end_time) values 
 ('$name', '$date', '$start_time', 
 '$end_time')";
 $link = $conn->query($mysql_qry);
 if($link===TRUE) {
     echo "Event added Successfully";
 }
 else {

     echo "Failed to add event";
 }
 $conn->close();

 ?>
```

Java:
[image]

I Tried all the formats for dates and time that i found but i keep getting the error "Failed to add event". Any ideas? Thank you

[Github](https://github.com/thathana1521/MedicalAppointmentOrganization/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/thomas/medicalappointmentorganization/EventBooking.java)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== true`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.

Comment: Please take the time to actually paste your java code instead of adding an image, which may get taken off any time.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in the wrong variable in when making a call.

Comment: Your Java code is using terrible old legacy date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. As of JDBC 4.2, we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database, no need for strings.

Comment: I am very new to this. I editted my code adding github repository link to show you the full java code. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echoing "Failed to add event" echo mysqli_error($conn) and then you will know what SQL error you are getting and can try to fix it from there